# adding markers dynamically on the map in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, maps, markers, blackberry-maps

i have to add markers to the map and also display the previous latitude and longitude.

So far i have added the previous latitude and longitude to a Vector and display on the map, but the new values and past value are all displayed at the same time, is there way i can add the new values as and when they arrive, and the past values are already there on the map.

Something like using Overlay in Android.

Could someone please tell me if there is any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue, just incase anyone has the sample problem, here is some part of my code:
this is for BB Os 6.

```
      MapDataModel data = map.getModel();  
      MapLocation location = new MapLocation(latitude,longitude,"My Location",null);
      int locationID = data.add((Mappable)location,"location");                             
      data.tag(locationID, "Location");  
      Mappable datamap = (Mappable) location;
      data.add(datamap,"Location",true);
      data.setVisible("Location");
```